# Reset server(VM) status to ACTIVE using REST API Nova

Tags: openstack-nova

When Server(VM) status is in ERROR How to reset the status back to Active using REST API (Nova).

CLI For .e.g nova reset-state --active vm

Answer (score 0):

From the openstack nova API documentation **https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/**

To reset the status of VM using API: https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/#reset-server-state-os-resetstate-action

> /servers/{server_id}/action - Reset Server State (os-resetState Action)

**Request body**:

> {
>       "os-resetState": {
>           "state": "active"
>       } }

**Response**:

> If successful, this method does not return content in the response
>   body.